# How does a Java application keeps on running even when main thread has finished execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java-threads

When an application is started via main method in Java and it spins other user threads(not daemon) for tasks such as :

- User Thread-01 : Loading Cache From Database
- User Thread-02 : Perform application startup tasks like running diagnostics
- User Thread-03 : Miscellaneous tasks

The user threads started by main thread will complete execution at some point in time and terminate. This will cause the main thread to terminate eventually and the application will stop running. But, as we see so many applications which once started keep on running and if we take a thread dump, we can see the main thread at the very bottom. This means the main thread is not terminated which means the user threads started are not terminated.

How is this achieved ? I mean what are standard programming constructs and logics to keep threads alive without running them through an infinite for or while loop ?

Thanks for going through the question. Every helpful reply will add to our knowledge.

Comment: Do you have an example that demonstrates this?

Comment: And also: There is no parent-child relationship when you start a thread or something. When you start a thread it's an independent thread within your process.

Comment: Are you referring to console apps, gui apps, or web apps?

Comment: Hi @akuzminykh, any application can be an example, a web application, a server such as tomcat, a desktop based application, an enterprise level banking application.

Comment: @BasilBourque we can take example of any application be it enterprise level application, a server, web application, a text editor, anything can be an example which keeps on running but, without making use of infinite loops to keep threads alive.

Comment: Your Question is a bit unclear. Do you have a goal to accomplish or a problem to solve? Or are you asking out of curiosity how certain kinds of apps such as a Swing or JavaFX app can continue to run with no apparent active execution?

Comment: @BasilBourque The question is very specific about, how an application's threads are sustained without making them run into finite loops so that the application doesn't dies once all the threads running at a moment are terminated for that application. 
Any such examples of graceful/logical sustenance of application's threads without infinite loops are welcome. :)

Comment: For what reason do you want an app running indefinitely doing nothing? If all other threads have completed, and you have no further work to accomplish, why should your main thread continue? Why not let the app exit?

Comment: @BasilBourque visualize it like this ... we have a website which is alive even when no one is opening the web page in the browser ... which means the application is running even when no one is interacting with it ... if we say that it is the web server which is running in background and not the actual web application .... but, then how is the web application is running indefinitely even when no one is interacting with it. 

I hope I am making myself clear the right words in right order :)

Answer (score 6):

## Executors framework

You said:

> spins other user threads

Hopefully you are not addressing `Thread` objects directly. Since Java 5, for most purposes we can be using the Executors framework to manage work on background threads. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) by Oracle.

```java
ExecutorService es = Executors. … ;
es.submit( yourRunnableOrCallableHere ) ;  // Optional: Capture the returned `Future` object to track success/failure of your task.
…
es.shutdown() ;
```

### Background threads ending has no effect on main thread

You said:

> The user threads started by main thread will complete execution at some point in time and terminate. This will cause the main thread to terminate eventually and the application will stop running.

Not correct.

The main thread ends when it has no more work to do. Background threads may end before the main thread, or after the main thread. The background threads termination does *not* cause the main thread to end.

Here is some example code to demonstrate this behavior. This app performs a thread-dump and then runs a task in the background which also performs a thread dump. Both main thread and background thread sleep a few seconds.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadInfo;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Threading
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Threading app = new Threading();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "---------------|  main thread  |------------------------------------" );
        System.out.println( "Bonjour. " + Instant.now() );
        System.out.println( Threading.threadDump( true , true ) );

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executorService.submit(
                ( ) -> {
                    System.out.println( "---------------|  background thread  |------------------------------------" );
                    System.out.println( "DEBUG - Starting background thread. " + Instant.now() );
                    System.out.println( "DEBUG - Sleeping background thread. " + Instant.now() );
                    try {Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 2 ).toMillis() );} catch ( InterruptedException e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
                    System.out.println( Threading.threadDump( true , true ) );
                    System.out.println( "DEBUG - Ending background thread. " + Instant.now() );
                }
        );

        executorService.shutdown();  // Always be sure to shutdown  your executor services.
        try {Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ).toMillis() );} catch ( InterruptedException e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
        System.out.println( "---------------|  main thread  |------------------------------------" );
        System.out.println( Threading.threadDump( true , true ) );
        System.out.println( "DEBUG - Main thread ending. " + Instant.now() );
    }

    // `threadDump` method taken from: https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump
    private static String threadDump ( boolean lockedMonitors , boolean lockedSynchronizers )
    {
        StringBuffer threadDump = new StringBuffer( System.lineSeparator() );
        ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        for ( ThreadInfo threadInfo : threadMXBean.dumpAllThreads( lockedMonitors , lockedSynchronizers ) )
        {
            String message = "Thread: " + threadInfo.getThreadId() + " | " + threadInfo.getThreadName();
            threadDump.append( message ).append( System.lineSeparator() );
//            threadDump.append( threadInfo.toString() );
        }
        return threadDump.toString();
    }
}
```

When we sleep the background thread for less time than the main thread (2 seconds versus 5), notice that the main thread continues. The background thread ending has no effect on the main thread continuing or ending.

When run, notice how launching the executor service with a submitted task results in two more threads with IDs 14 & 15 here. Then after the background task ends and the executor service is closed, the thread with ID 14 disappears. Notice how the main thread *does not end*, continuing to do work — contradicting your statement in the Question.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Users/basilbourque/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.5981.155/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 EAP.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=49389:/Users/basilbourque/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.5981.155/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 EAP.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/basilbourque/IdeaProjects/Loom/target/classes work.basil.example.Threading
---------------|  main thread  |------------------------------------
Bonjour. 2020-12-18T07:30:21.107455Z

Thread: 1 | main
Thread: 2 | Reference Handler
Thread: 3 | Finalizer
Thread: 4 | Signal Dispatcher
Thread: 11 | Common-Cleaner
Thread: 12 | Monitor Ctrl-Break
Thread: 13 | Notification Thread

---------------|  background thread  |------------------------------------
DEBUG - Starting background thread. 2020-12-18T07:30:21.268025Z
DEBUG - Sleeping background thread. 2020-12-18T07:30:21.268225Z

Thread: 1 | main
Thread: 2 | Reference Handler
Thread: 3 | Finalizer
Thread: 4 | Signal Dispatcher
Thread: 11 | Common-Cleaner
Thread: 12 | Monitor Ctrl-Break
Thread: 13 | Notification Thread
Thread: 14 | pool-1-thread-1
Thread: 15 | Attach Listener

DEBUG - Ending background thread. 2020-12-18T07:30:23.275729Z
---------------|  main thread  |------------------------------------

Thread: 1 | main
Thread: 2 | Reference Handler
Thread: 3 | Finalizer
Thread: 4 | Signal Dispatcher
Thread: 11 | Common-Cleaner
Thread: 12 | Monitor Ctrl-Break
Thread: 13 | Notification Thread
Thread: 15 | Attach Listener

DEBUG - Main thread ending. 2020-12-18T07:30:26.271499Z

Process finished with exit code 0
```

For fun, try that code but reverse the durations. Use 5 seconds versus 2 seconds to see the background threads outlive the main thread.

## A web server is busy listening, all the time

You said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65346065/how-does-a-java-application-keeps-on-running-even-when-main-thread-has-finished?noredirect=1#comment115538772_65346065):

> visualize it like this ... we have a website which is alive even when no one is opening the web page in the browser ... which means the application is running even when no one is interacting with it ... if we say that it is the web server which is running in background and not the actual web application .... but, then how is the web application is running indefinitely even when no one is interacting with it.

Regarding "we have a website which is alive even when no one is opening the web page in the browser", no your web site is not "alive". Without any pending HTTP request to handle, your Java Servlet is *not* executing. Your servlet is loaded and initialized, but is *not* executing until a request arrives.

Regarding "which means the application is running even when no one is interacting with it", no your web app is not running, as I said above. Your Java servlet code is not executing. When a request arrives, the web container automatically invokes your servlet's code in a thread. Ultimately that servlet code results in the generation of content sent back to the web browser in a response. Your servlet code's execution ends. The thread used for that execution either ends or is returned to a thread pool (an internal decision for your web container to make). I am ignoring [Push technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) and [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for the sake of simplicity.

Regarding: "if we say that it is the web server which is running in background and not the actual web application", the web server is always running an extra thread to listen for incoming requests.

➥ This may be the root of your confusion: ***A web server is always busy***, busy listening for incoming connections, whether or not executing your Java servlet code.

- A web server has one thread dedicated to working with the host OS to listen on the network for incoming connections.
- A web server launches *other* threads as needed to respond to a request by formulating and sending a response.

Regarding: "how is the web application is running indefinitely even when no one is interacting with it", you are forgetting that the host OS is interacting with the web container, whether or not users are interacting with your web app. The web container maintains a thread listening for incoming connections. That thread sits blocked, waiting on a notification by the host operating system's networking stack of an incoming request. (My description here is generalized and simplified — I'm no networking expert — but suffices for the point being made here.)

When a request comes in over the network, the host OS informs the web container. This notification unblocks the listening thread. The listening thread dispatches the request to a new thread, resulting in your Java servlet's code executing. Meanwhile the request-listening thread of the web container goes back to being blocked to await another notification from the host OS’ network stack about yet another incoming request.

That blocked listening thread is what explains/enables the web server running continuously and indefinitely. Your web app, in contrast, runs in spurts, only in response to a request.

Your question is a credit to the genius and success of Java Servlet technology. The very purpose of Java Servlet is to abstract away all these details about listening for network activity, translating packets to text to decipher a request, parsing that request, mapping the request's contents to being the responsibility of a particular servlet, ensuring that particular servlet is loaded and initialized, and eventually calling a specific method in your servlet code defined by the Servlet spec.

## A user app is busy waiting for input, all the time

Similar to a web server being always busy listening for incoming requests, [console apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application) and [gui apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) are both always busy listening for user input. They may seem idle at times, but are not.

While user apps do not spin continuously on the CPU, they do maintain a thread that works with the host OS to be informed of user events such as keyboard typing and mouse motion/clicks.

Comment: A nice answer with great explanation! A year ago, I used to go through your answers on the modern date-time and I found them so well-crafted that I took a leave of a couple of days from my work and studied the modern date-time API as much as I could. Apart from your answers on date-time, I found Ole's answers also very helpful. For a month or so, I have seen you posting answers for multithreading and concurrency questions and it looks like I am going to take a few days of leave again to study the Java's modern API on concurrency.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Glad to hear I've been of assistance. As for this month, I have been intrigued by the new [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) technology, with virtual threads, coming to Java soon or semi-soon. I find asking and answering questions on Stack Overflow to be a good way to enhance my learning. Indeed I thought at first that a Project Loom solution might apply to this Question, but turned out to be irrelevant once I got into it.

Comment: Hey @BasilBourque thanks a lot for so much effort and details. Your reply is really helpful. I appreciate all the explanation. I can use all the details. A delightful answer/comment I must say. I will run the code posted by you and will post here if I have any further queries. Thank you :) :)